# Implement an MDM server

Tags: ios, server, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I'm trying to implement a server side solution to remotely control permissions in and iOS device, on demand.
From what I've read it is possible using the MDM protocol and MDM push notifications, which allow my server to remotely change restrictions in an iOS device, for instance, or even lock the device, on demand.

I know that the iOS device must install an MDM configuration profile to be able to be remotely managed. I also know that the server must have an APNS certificate with MDM permissions.

My question is: do I have to be an MDM vendor and/or join the Apple Developer Enterprise Program in order to generate the APNS certificate with MDM permissions ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have a company developer account registered with a DUNS number before you can be accepted into the MDM program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Apple Developer Enterprise Program if you want implement MDM server by yourself. There is no need of Developer enterprise program to generate APNS certificate. You can generate APNS certificate from any apple id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have to do anything to write your own personal MDM server except register for and receive an APNS certificate and follow the protocols.

If you want to sell your server and have it authorized by Apple, then you need to register obviously.  I would certainly not buy one which wasn't.

You need an APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) certificate in order to connect to the APNS Servers to have your MDM server work.  You use the certificate to validate who you are before you are allowed to send Push Notification messages.  This requires an Apple Id.

Your MDM server also needs to be running on an TLS secured server and you use that certificate to sign the MDM profile you install on a device which you want to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need Apple Developer Enterprise Account. Only Apple Account will not work. Contact Apple Support and ask them to provide you MDM Vendor rights.
In order to send MDM commands you will require Push Certificate Signed by MDM Vendor certificate.

This [MDM Vendor](http://www.blueboxmoon.com/wordpress/?p=877) tutorial will help you.